# What is a OpenWRT "Linux kernel with minimal file system"?

Tags: openwrt

I'm trying to install OpenWRT onto my home router ([Mercury MAC1200R V2](https://firmware-selector.openwrt.org/?version=22.03.0&target=ramips%2Fmt76x8&id=mercury_mac1200r-v2)). The OpenWRT device page has no factory image, but a kernel image is provided that seems useful for a factory install:

> Linux kernel with minimal file system. Useful for first installation or recovery.

And that is the only documentation that I can find.

What does this minimal filesystem? What capability does the router have (and lose) after flashing it? (is lan ports, dhcp and ssh still working?) And how do I move on from here to a full OpenWRT installation?

Comment: You might get better answers to this question on [the OpenWRT forum](https://forum.openwrt.org/).

Comment: Installation is supposed to be covered on the [OpenWRT device page for your router](https://openwrt.org/toh/mercury/mac1200r), but as I write this it only covers v1.1 of the MAC100R, not v2.